# How to define a command with `limits`

Tags: macros

I would like to define the following command:

```
\newcommand{\prob}[1]{\underset{#1}{\mathbb{P}}
```

Often, parameter `1` remains unfilled. Is it the correct way to define this operator? I was also considering using the `\limits` command, but I don't have clues on how I can make it work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should employ the `\DeclareMathOperator*` macro of the `amsmath` package to define `\prob`.

- In display-math style, LaTeX will place the optional argument below `\mathbb{P}`  automatically, just as is the case with `\lim` and `\max`.
- In inline math mode, you'd need to place `\limits` immediately after `\Prob` in order to place the argument *below* `\mathbb{P}` -- again exactly analogously to `\lim` and `\max`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\DeclareMathOperator*{\prob}{\mathbb{P}}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle 
  \prob  % no arg.
  \quad 
  \prob_{x}
  \quad
  \textstyle
  \prob_{x}
  \quad
  \prob\limits_{x}$
\end{document}
```